# pgfplots - size of plot and bars don't match the desired values

Tags: pgfplots

I created a plot with [pgfplot](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) and tried to style it the way I want it to be. For that I chose to add labels and text outside of the block `axis`, as I want to make a couple of nodes to explain the plot.

The `axis` block has already the options `width`, `height` and `/bar/width` with `cm` values. However the specified values are not correctly used. So far I could only make the width of the entire plot the desired width. I added some lines as guides to make it clear.

[image]

And the script is as follows:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, 12pt, a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    ybar stacked,
    width = 5cm,
    height = 8cm,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    axis x line = none,
    ytick=\empty,
    ymin = 0,
    scale only axis=true,
    bar width=2cm,
    symbolic x coords = {2016,2017},
    every axis plot/.append style={
          fill
        }]

    \addplot[red] coordinates {(2017,47.4) (2016,43.9)};
    \addplot[blue] coordinates {(2017,6.8) (2016,6.3)};
    \addplot[green] coordinates {(2017,18.5) (2016,17.6)};
    \addplot[orange] coordinates {(2017,5.4) (2016,5.2)};
\end{axis}

\draw (0,0) -- (5cm,0) -- (5cm,8cm); % The desired space of entire plot
\draw (2cm,0) -- (2cm,8cm);          %   and the right edge of first bar
\draw (3cm,0) -- (3cm,8cm);          %   and the left edge of second bar

\begin{scope}[xshift=-2cm,yshift=-0.8cm]
    \draw[line width=3mm,red] (0,0) -- ++(0:3mm) node[right, black, align=left] {\footnotesize Lorem Ipsum};
    \draw[line width=3mm,blue] (4,0) -- ++(0:3mm) node[right, black, align=left] {\footnotesize Consetetur Sadipscing};
    \draw[line width=3mm,green] (0,-0.6) -- ++(0:3mm) node[right, black, align=left] {\footnotesize Magna Aliquyam};
    \draw[line width=3mm,orange] (4,-0.6) -- ++(0:3mm) node[right, black, align=left] {\footnotesize Diam Nonumy Eirmod Tempor};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How can I make the bars the exact width I want?

Answer (score 1):

This is a not too serious answer but just the observation that `bar width=pi*1cm` seems to give you what you want. ;-) (The vertical excess can be removed by setting `ymax`, so this is more serious. And I guess you know that one can create legends in a different way.)

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    ybar stacked,
    width = 5cm,
    height = 8cm,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    axis x line = none,
    axis y line = none,
    ytick=\empty,
    ymin = 0,
    scale only axis=true,
    bar width={pi*1cm},
    ymax=78,
    symbolic x coords = {2016,2017},
    every axis plot/.append style={
          fill
        }]

    \addplot[red] coordinates {(2017,47.4) (2016,43.9)};
    \addplot[blue] coordinates {(2017,6.8) (2016,6.3)};
    \addplot[green] coordinates {(2017,18.5) (2016,17.6)};
    \addplot[orange] coordinates {(2017,5.4) (2016,5.2)};
\end{axis}

\draw (0,0) -- (5cm,0) -- (5cm,8cm); % The desired space of entire plot
\draw (2cm,0) -- (2cm,8cm);          %   and the right edge of first bar
\draw (3cm,0) -- (3cm,8cm);          %   and the left edge of second bar

\begin{scope}[xshift=-2cm,yshift=-0.8cm]
    \draw[line width=3mm,red] (0,0) -- ++(0:3mm) node[right, black, align=left] {\footnotesize Lorem Ipsum};
    \draw[line width=3mm,blue] (4,0) -- ++(0:3mm) node[right, black, align=left] {\footnotesize Consetetur Sadipscing};
    \draw[line width=3mm,green] (0,-0.6) -- ++(0:3mm) node[right, black, align=left] {\footnotesize Magna Aliquyam};
    \draw[line width=3mm,orange] (4,-0.6) -- ++(0:3mm) node[right, black, align=left] {\footnotesize Diam Nonumy Eirmod Tempor};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]